# How to use Telegram API (to include Chat Application) in my existing android app?

Tags: android, telegram

I want to use telegram APIs in order to develop chatting feature in My Existing Android App. 
I am not getting how to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it is a good idea to take a look at the **Telegram Database Library (Beta)** from here [TDLib](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib) (Russian, but translate with Google) and the [Java doc](https://javadoc.tlgrm.ru/org/drinkless/td/libcore/telegram/package-summary.html) (English) from here.

The information is a little poor yet, but I think you can understand it.

Comment: OK Sir. I will post a new one

Answer (score 0):

Use this [API](https://core.telegram.org/).

Refer to the **Getting Started** section to integrate Telegram in your app.

Comment: I imported the Telegram-master(github) project into my Android Studio IDE. Then, I edited the BuildVars.java file which includes APP_ID & APP_HASH. It was asking google-services.json file when I ran the project. Somehow, I got that file by Generating Signed APK(Not created because of absence of google-services.json file) & KeyStorefile for the project. After placing google-services.json file with in app folder of the project. I am getting  Error:Execution failed for task ':TMessagesProj:processArmv7DebugGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'org.telegram.messenger.beta'

Comment: Either post a different question or update your question with this new query and the error log.