# No matching client found for package name org.telegram.messenger.beta while running the Telegram-master project (downloaded from gitHub) )

Tags: android, telegram

With reference to the Telegram Integration asked here [My Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41019144/how-to-use-telegram-api-to-include-chat-application-in-my-existing-android-app/41019232?noredirect=1#comment69397361_41019232)  ,    I have imported the telegram-master Project source code into my Android Studio IDE from the GitHub  [GitHub Link](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram)

After first time running, It was displaying error of google-services.json file needed as shown in fig.1  [image: fig 1]
"File google-services.json is missing from module root folder. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it".

Some of the files changes as mentioned in the telegram official website.
**The APP_ID & APP_HASH has been updated as received for my telegram Account contact number.**

**BuildVars.java**

```
/*
 * This is the source code of Telegram for Android v. 3.x.x.
 * It is licensed under GNU GPL v. 2 or later.
 * You should have received a copy of the license in this archive (see LICENSE).
 *
 * Copyright Nikolai Kudashov, 2013-2016.
 */

    package org.telegram.messenger;

    public class BuildVars {
        public static boolean DEBUG_VERSION = false;
        public static int BUILD_VERSION = 851;
        public static String BUILD_VERSION_STRING = "3.13";
        public static int APP_ID = *22**; //obtain your own APP_ID at https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id
        public static String APP_HASH = "01a66ec**********ea979**********"; //obtain your own APP_HASH at https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id
        public static String HOCKEY_APP_HASH = "your-hockeyapp-api-key-here";
        public static String HOCKEY_APP_HASH_DEBUG = "your-hockeyapp-api-key-here";
        public static String GCM_SENDER_ID = "760348033672";
        public static String SEND_LOGS_EMAIL = "email@gmail.com";
        public static String BING_SEARCH_KEY = ""; //obtain your own KEY at https://www.bing.com/dev/en-us/dev-center
        public static String FOURSQUARE_API_KEY = ""; //obtain your own KEY at https://developer.foursquare.com/
        public static String FOURSQUARE_API_ID = ""; //obtain your own API_ID at https://developer.foursquare.com/
        public static String FOURSQUARE_API_VERSION = "20150326";
    }
```

Downloaded google-servives.json file (downloaded from here [**link**](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add))
While doing so, I gave app name as **TMessagesProj** & Package name as **com.telegram**. I was asking SHA Key.

After generating Keystorefile.jks I got SHA1 Key from command prompt., Finally, I got google-servives.json

**google-servives.json**

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "9063***82727",
    "project_id": "tmessagesproj-767a5"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:906349682727:android:31bf726991d01aca",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "org.telegram"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "906349682727-vcvhs6liiqgfdfc90vasor1vf9cfsqrp.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 1,
          "android_info": {
            "package_name": "org.telegram",
            "certificate_hash": "11D45CD77CC61E236233BD1A2FB74A0BE1184C15"
          }
        },
        {
          "client_id": "906***682727-n0finerekh0ajii3qr4dqm0rd8fnl4ck.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "AIzaSyAqyKxdPU4mcDElWWHnJXuOwTtz_JP****"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 1
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

**After adding google-services.json file in the app  i.e., TMessagesProj**, it is giving error as shown in fig.2 [image: figure 2.]

**Can somebody tell me where I am going wrong ? Is there any mistake in giving package name while downloading json file ??**

Comment: where you can put your google-servives.json file

Comment: According to the majority, within the app folder. In my case, I placed under TMessagesProj.  And, there is no such folder named as 'beta' . i.e. within **org.telegram.messenger.beta**

Answer (score 2):

filling the file BuildVars.java

tab BuildsVariants edit armv7Debug -> armv7Release

[image]